# Train program to understand high and low value in machine learning

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I am generating alerts by reading dataset for KPI (key performance indicator) . My algorithm is looking into historical data and based on that I am able to capture if there's sudden spike in data.  But I am  generating false alarms . For example KPI1 is historically at .5 but reaches value 12, which is kind of spike . 
Same way KPI2 also reaches from .5 to 12. But I know that KPI reaching from .5 to 12 is not a big deal and I need not to capture that . same way KPI2 reaching from .5 to 12 is big deal and I need to capture that. 
I want to train my program to understand what is high value ,  low value or normal value  for each KPI. 
Could you experts tell me which is best ML algorithm is for this and any package in python I need to explore?

Comment: Are you looking at a time series? Or in other words at the time evolution of yours KPIs? How is your data structured? That would help us in helping you more effectively. Can you describe a little more your data and your output (how you define high and low)?

Comment: yes , I am looking at time series. Plotting KPI value on y-axis and Timestamp on x-axis. using historical data (30 days), I get dynamic threshold (benchmark value)  and based on that I find peaks in data set (7 days). jump in value for KPI1 from .5 (benchmark value )  to 12 (Peak value) is not a big deal but same is big deal for KPI2 (assuming that KPI1 and KPI2 data set is kind of similar).

Comment: Ok, then I would argue that is not a standard classification problem... You should look in time series prediction.

Comment: Looks like this is classification issue . Let me give common example . Hemoglobin rise from 12 to 17 is considered as good rise  but platelets rising 150,000 to 200,000 is normal rise but if same rises to 450,000 then it's good rise. I have to identify good rise based on item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the classification problem. You can use classic logistic regression algorithm to classify any given sample into either high value, low value or normal value.

Quoting from the Wikipedia,

> In statistics, multinomial logistic regression is a classification
>   method that generalizes logistic regression to multiclass problems,
>   i.e. with more than two possible discrete outcomes. That is, it is
>   a model that is used to predict the probabilities of the different
>   possible outcomes of a categorically distributed dependent variable,
>   given a set of independent variables (which may be real-valued,
>   binary-valued, categorical-valued, etc.)

To perform multi-class classification in python, sklearn library can be useful.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html